# Gradle can't make Android javadoc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am having a bad time trying to generate javadoc for my Android project.
I have no clue on how to make it works, InteliJ/Android Studio built in tool doesn't works.

With command line:
`gradlew javadoc`

with this task defined in build.gradle:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../docs")
}
```

I get the result:

```
> Configure project :library
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:javadoc
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\MainActivity.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
                          ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\MainActivity.java:4: error: package androidx.appcompat.app does not exist
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
                             ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\MainActivity.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class AppCompatActivity
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\MainActivity.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 ^
  symbol: class RequiresApi
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\PermissionsHandler.java:6: error: package androidx.core.app does not exist
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
                        ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\Android Studio\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\userdev\myapp\PermissionsHandler.java:7: error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
                            ^
...
...
25 errors

> Task :app:javadoc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Users\sfrx7348\Documents\Android Studio\Morinant\app\build\tmp\javadoc\javadoc.options'
```

Any help would be realy welcome.
Have a nice day !

Comment: I am struggling with this too...